# Approximate $ \ \large \int_{0}^{1} \frac{e^x-1}{x} dx $

Tags: sequences-and-series

Approximate $ \ \large \int_{0}^{1} \frac{e^x-1}{x} dx =\int_0^1 (1+\frac{x}{2!}+\frac{x^2}{3!}+\cdots+\frac{x^{n-1}}{n!}+\cdots) dx \ $

for an Error $ \leq 10^{-6} \ $

**Answer:**

$ \ \large \int_{0}^{1} \frac{e^x-1}{x} dx \\ =\int_0^1 (1+\frac{x}{2!}+\frac{x^2}{3!}+\cdots+\frac{x^{n-1}}{n!}+\cdots) dx \\ =[x+\frac{x^2}{2 (2!)}+\frac{x^3}{3(3!)}+\cdots]_{0}^{1} , \ (Integrating) \\ = 1+\frac{1}{2(2!)}+\frac{1}{3(3!)}+\frac{1}{4(4!)} +\cdots+\frac{1}{n(n!)}+\cdots$

**This is a series.**

**How to approximate for an $ \ Error \leq 10^{-6} \ $ ?**

How many term should be included ?

**Help me out**

Comment: Do you know Lagrange Error Bound?

Comment: Note that the 'closed' form is $\text{Ei}(1)-\gamma$

Comment: You need to estimate $$\sum_{n = k+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n\cdot n!}\,.$$ If you estimate that by $$\frac{1}{k+1}\sum_{n = k+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}\,,$$ you're not making a huge overestimate, since the terms decrease so fast. Can you further estimate that remainder?

Comment: I can't estimate the remainder. .

Comment: Please consider \cdots to give $\cdots$ instead of a random number of full-stops. For example $a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n$ instead of $a_1+a_2+......+a_n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sum_{n\geq N}\frac{1}{n\cdot n!}\leq\frac{N+2}{N}\sum_{n\geq N}\frac{1}{(n+2)n!}=\frac{N+2}{N} \sum_{n\geq N}\left[\frac{1}{(n+1)!}-\frac{1}{(n+2)!}\right]=\frac{N+2}{N(N+1)!} $$
and the RHS is smaller than $2\cdot 10^{-7}$ as soon as $N\geq 10$, hence 
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{9}\frac{1}{n\cdot n!} = \frac{1205165611}{914457600}=\color{green}{1.3179021}\color{red}{214324}\ldots$$
is an approximation of $I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^x-1}{x}\,dx$ within the given accuracy.

---

Alternative (Beuker-style) approach. The integral
$$ J=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^x-1}{x}P_5(2x-1)\,dx $$
is extremely close to zero since $\frac{e^x-1}{x}$ is an entire function. It is related to $I$ via
$$ J=4118e-\frac{335777}{30}-I $$
hence $$I\approx 4118e-\frac{335777}{30}=\color{green}{1.317902}\color{red}{927681}\ldots$$

Answer (score 1):

**just a hint**

UseTaylor-Lagrange formula

$$e^x-1=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac {x^k}{k!}+\frac {x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}e^c $$

with $0 <c <x\le 1.$